# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Score'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, int

I have searched for a while and can't find and answer hoping someone can help me!. What I am trying to do is save my Score and transfer it to a different scene. With this code I have here I get the error :

> error CS0029: Cannt implicitly convert type 'int' To 'Score'

I am rather new to unity script as well.

Here are the two scripts I am using

Script 1 Score.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    static public int score = 0;
    static public int highScore = 0;

    static Score instance;

    static public void AddPoint() {
        if(instance.run.dead)
            return;

        score++;

        if(score > highScore) {
            highScore = score;
        }
    }
    Running run;

    void Start() {
        instance = this;
        GameObject player_go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        if (player_go == null) {
            Debug.LogError("could not find an object with tag 'Player'.");
        }
        run = player_go.GetComponent<Running> ();
        score = 0;
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("score", score);
    }

    void Update () {
        guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
}
```

and the second script to get it to the other scene

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GetScore : MonoBehaviour {

    Score score;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("score");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        guiText.text = "Score: " + score;

    }
}
```

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: You can't run C# code in code snippet tool. It'is for javascript, html and css.

Comment: Yes, please don't use Stack Snippet for non JS / HTML / CSS code, I have removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("score");
```

The error is caused by above line. `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` as it name states will return an integer. And now see how you declare the `score` variable:

```
Score score;
```

This causes the variable `score` have a type `Score` class, not `int`.

I suppose you want to set the variable `score` in `Score` class. Since you declare the variable `score` as `static public`, that makes things easy. You don't have to create an instance of `Score`, just use the class name `Score` **(with capital S)** instead:

```
Score.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help I did what you said to do. I don't get errors anymore which is a good thing!. but on the deathScene it does not show the Score the score sits at "0" any idea on why it is doing that?

Comment: Try printing the value of `score` in `OnDestroy()`, we'll see if that function is called and if the score is correctly incremented or not.

Comment: where you call AddPoint

Comment: I did Debug.Log(score); under the void OnDestroy() and it gives out a number.

Comment: Ok now try printing `Score.score` in `Start()` and `Update()` method of `GetScore` script.

Comment: sorry I have no idea on how to do that, i'm new to unity i know some things but not much could you tell me how to? if so thank you!

Comment: you should print your value using `Score.score`  in your deathscene   too like this  `guiText.text = "Score: " + Score.score;`

Comment: OHHH, i'm so stupid!! thank both of you so much for helping me! I really appreciate it

Comment: Hahaha, that's what I expected. But @user2320445 said it first. Thanks a lot dude :D

Answer (score 2):

`PLayerPrefs.GetInt` will return an `int` but you put a `Score` class clone to assign the returning value of 
`PLayerPrefs.GetInt` to it , `int` cant become `Score` so if you want to access the score class variable you should do this

```
void Start () {
    score=score.GetComponent<Score>();
    score.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("score");

}
```

because your score varaible is `static` you can use this too

```
 void Start () {

    Score.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("score");

}
```